# External elements slowing down canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am developing a game using several canvases (3) on top of one another. I am close to finishing the game and I haven't yet optimized the performance.

Regardless, my main concern is that the game has performed pretty well so far, but being close to finish I am building a simple web page around the canvas to give a frame to the game. I am talking just putting the title of the game and a few links here and there, but suddenly the game is now choppy and slow!!! If remove those elements everything is smooth again.

The culprits are:

- The game title above the canvas (styled with text-shadow).
- four buttons below the canvas to redirect to other sites and credits.

Is it possible that this few static elements interfere with the rendering of the game?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you somehow causing the DOM to reformat + rebuild the page? Are the extra elements causing the GPU to run out of memory and therefore bounce things off non-GPU memory/storage?

Comment: Use Chrome rendering settings to debug your app

Comment: first quick test i would do would be to : use a single canvas in the web page, render title/buttons on two off-screen canvas (the smaller the better), then drawImage game+buttons+title on the single canvas each frame.

Comment: A text-shadow (and rounded corners, blur, box-shadow) is one of the most expensive thing the browser can render, and it calculates and renders it per frame. If you replace your text + shadow with an image (or build an image using a canvas) you should see increase in performance.

Comment: markE the only things that gets changes outside the canvas is the text of a div, but this occurs per input not per frame.
K3N, I think you just nailed it!

I don't understand why the text-shadow recalculate per frame, though... Isn't it a static element that once rendered stays the same..? How could I use a canvas to achieve the same effect?

Also the canavases I use have rounded corners, is there a way to substitute those too..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything with shadows, rounded corners or expensive effects such as blur cost a lot to render.

Modern browsers try to optimize this in various way but there are special cases which they can't get around just like that (updated render engines using 3D hardware can help in the future).

Shadows are closely related to blurring and needs to be composited per frame due to the possibility that the background, shadow color, blur range etc. could change. Rounded corners forces the browser to create an alpha mask instead of doing just a rectangular clip. The browser may cache some of these operations, but they'll add up in the end.

## Text Shadow

A workaround is to "cache" the shadowed text as an image. It can be a pre-made image from Photoshop or it could be made dynamically using a canvas element. Then display this instead of the text+shadow.

#### Example

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    txt = "SHADOW HEADER";

// we need to do this twice as when we set width of canvas, state is cleared
ctx.font = "bold 28px sans-serif";

c.width = ctx.measureText(txt).width + 20; // add space for shadow
c.height = 50;                             // estimated

// and again...
ctx.font = "bold 28px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.shadowBlur = 9;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 9;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 9;
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
ctx.fillStyle = "#aaa";

ctx.fillText(txt, 0, 0);
```

```css
body {background:#7C3939}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

The canvas element can now be placed as needed. In addition you could convert the canvas to an image and use that without the extra overhead.

## Rounded Corners

Rounded corners on an element is also expensive and there are no easy way around this - the corners need to be cut one way or another and question is which method is fastest.

- Let browser do it using CSS
- Overlay the element with the outer corners covered in the same color as background - clunky but can be fast as no clipping is needed. However, more data need to be composited.
- Use a mask in canvas directly via `globalCompositeOperation`. The chances are this would be the slowest method. Performance tests must be made for this scenario to find out which one works best overall.
- Make a compromise and remove rounded corners all together.

## Links

Also these could be replaced by clickable images. It's a bit more tedious but also these could be made dynamically using a canvas allowing the text to change ad-hoc.

## CSS

I would also recommend experimenting with `position: fixed;` for some of the elements. When `fixed` is used, some browsers renders that element separately (gives it its own bitmap). This may be more efficient in some cases.

But do make some performance tests to see what combination is the best for your scenario.

Comment: hum what ? rendering on the canvas should not make change the flow of the DOM, and browser should not repaint other elements, whatever there styles. (Try it with your chrome dev tool "Enable paint Flashing") What's this idea of rendering every frame ? Even if you don't do anything on the page browser will just re-render every shadowed elements? Naaa I can't believe it. Or is it the call to `requestAnimationFrame` which will trigger this? Please can you provide any references about it ?

Comment: OP said that he placed his elements **around** the canvas, So either it's the styles he applied directly to the canvas, either as pointed out by @markE, he's updating something in the DOM every frame.